# Merge 2 tables to create 1 table: Same rows, different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, kable, kableextra

I have two tables with the same rows, but they each have different columns. Is it possible to merge them together? I am using the `kabbleExtra` package to output tables.

```
           18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+ Total
Democrat    11.8  18.4  14.2   7.1   6.2   4.5 2.1  64.3
Republican   3.1   5.0   4.0   5.4   5.3   3.5 1.7  28.0
Other        2.0   0.9   1.2   2.1   0.7   0.6 0.2   7.7
Total       17.0  24.3  19.4  14.5  12.2   8.6 4.1 100.0
```

```
           White Latino Asian African-American Other Total
Democrat    25.2   22.4  10.0              2.2   5.2  65.1
Republican  14.4    7.2   2.8              0.4   2.0  26.8
Other        2.5    4.1   0.9              0.0   0.6   8.1
Total       42.2   33.7  13.7              2.6   7.8 100.0
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
                             Ethnicity                                            Age
           White Latino Asian African-American Other Total    18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+ Total
Democrat    25.2   22.4  10.0              2.2   5.2  65.1    11.8  18.4  14.2   7.1   6.2  4.5 2.1   64.3
Republican  14.4    7.2   2.8              0.4   2.0  26.8    3.1   5.0   4.0   5.4   5.3   3.5 1.7   28.0
Other        2.5    4.1   0.9              0.0   0.6   8.1    2.0   0.9   1.2   2.1   0.7   0.6 0.2   7.7
Total       42.2   33.7  13.7              2.6   7.8 100.0    17.0  24.3  19.4  14.5  12.2  8.6 4.1   100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can merge the tables using dplyr:

```
> df1 %>% rownames_to_column('party') %>% 
+   inner_join(df2 %>% rownames_to_column('party'), by = 'party') %>% column_to_rownames('party')
           18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+ Total.x White Latino Asian African-American Other Total.y
Democrat    11.8  18.4  14.2   7.1   6.2   4.5 2.1    64.3  25.2   22.4  10.0              2.2   5.2    65.1
Republican   3.1   5.0   4.0   5.4   5.3   3.5 1.7    28.0  14.4    7.2   2.8              0.4   2.0    26.8
Other        2.0   0.9   1.2   2.1   0.7   0.6 0.2     7.7   2.5    4.1   0.9              0.0   0.6     8.1
Total       17.0  24.3  19.4  14.5  12.2   8.6 4.1   100.0  42.2   33.7  13.7              2.6   7.8   100.0
```

Data used:

```
> df1                                  
           18-24 25-34 35-44 45-54 55-64 65-74 75+ Total
Democrat    11.8  18.4  14.2   7.1   6.2   4.5 2.1  64.3
Republican   3.1   5.0   4.0   5.4   5.3   3.5 1.7  28.0
Other        2.0   0.9   1.2   2.1   0.7   0.6 0.2   7.7
Total       17.0  24.3  19.4  14.5  12.2   8.6 4.1 100.0
> df2
           White Latino Asian African-American Other Total
Democrat    25.2   22.4  10.0              2.2   5.2  65.1
Republican  14.4    7.2   2.8              0.4   2.0  26.8
Other        2.5    4.1   0.9              0.0   0.6   8.1
Total       42.2   33.7  13.7              2.6   7.8 100.0
>
```